# How can I "assign" a tab to be active?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm using firefox, some sites require its tab to be open for it to do its thing...

I've tried the ["Disable Page Visibility API"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disable-page-visibility/) add-on, but it doesn't seem to do the trick here.

the tab only "activates" if it's actually on my screen view, and if the cursor has "clicked" somewhere, not sure what kind of trackers is the site using, but is there such an add-on to work-around this?

Comment: Would setting "browser.tabs.loadInBackground" and "browser.zoom.updateBackgroundTabs" to "true" in about:config do the job?

Comment: @Didier Both are already "true", even setting them to "false" didn't do anything related unfortunately.

Comment: What about this one, "toolkit.lazyHiddenWindow", set to "false"? I have it set to "true" because I don't want any tabs or windows loading in the background, but if you set it to "false", you might get what you want, who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the tab to be active and viewed while you are using another,
the following extension might help.

The add-on
[Side View](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/side-view/)
seems to do just that, allowing the viewing of two tabs at the same time on the screen.

Comment: Since I'm using a mac, which already has split-view,
The tab needs to be "clicked on" if that makes sense, once I click on something else (browse elsewhere, it'd deactivate.)

Therefore I can't assign multiple tabs to be active (as in, using multiple tabs all together all active...

Comment: This add-on tricks two tabs to be visible instead of one, so my thought was that it might mark them both as active. If not, you will need to use something like Greasemonkey on the Mac to block focus-loss events from this website.

Comment: The add-on, unfortunately, didn't work, I tried some Greasemonkey's scrips and none worked too... the website I'm referring to has a timer that simply just stops when "out of focus?"

Comment: You could use the JavaScript debugger to find out where this is done, then disable it using Greasemonkey or even manual editing (for as long as the tab is open).

Comment: So after an hour of doing this, it appears that disabling multiple HandleEvents (focus/visibilityChange/blur) and "settimeout" API did the trick, although it doesn't always work flawlessly and some times even slows-down the timer for some reason.. now Hopefully this doesn't go against the site rules or something... considering I'm using it for multiple pages opened at once. Thanks for the info!